# How to obtain transfer function of the control system block diagram?

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory, linear-control

I want to design a robust control system using the internal model design specifications. The block diagram is the one shown below:

[image]

I am trying to obtain the transfer function $\ \frac{Y(s)}{R(s)} $ in order to acquire the characteristic polynomial of the closed loop system but for some reason I am stuck. This is what I have done so far:

$$ E_{a}(s) = R(s) - Y(s) $$

$$ U(s) = E_{a}(s)G_{c}(s) - KX(s) $$ ( $\ U(s) $: control input to the process $\ G(s) $)

$$ Y(s) = U(s)G(s) = E_{a}(s)G(s)G_{c}(s)-KX(s)G(s) $$

$\ $

$$ Y(s) = R(s)G(s)G_{c}(s) - Y(s)G(s)G_{c}(s) - KX(s)G(s) $$
$\  $

$$ Y(s) = \frac{G(s)[R(s)G_{c}(s)-KX(s)]}{1+G(s)G_{c}(s)} $$

From this point, I really don't know how to continue. Obviously the term that confuses me is $\ X(s) $. So, now how should I proceed and obtain the overall transfer function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you really have two different outputs for $G$. The image is a bit misleading in this regard, because it suggests that both $X$ and $Y$ are outputs of the same $G$.

For state feedback, its often useful to also look at the state space form of a system. For example, $G(s)$ in state space form is

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= A x + B u \\
y &= C x + D u
\end{align}
$$

Now, instead of this define a state space model that outputs all states:

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= A x + B u \\
y &= x
\end{align}
$$

This system has the transfer function $G_x(s) = (s I_n - A)^{-1}B$. Note: $I_n$ is a $n \times n$ identity matrix. The output $Y(s)$ is then

$$
Y(s) = C G_x(s) U(s) + D U(s)
$$

and so the original transfer function is

$$
G(s) = Y(s)/U(s) = C G_x(s) + D. \tag{1}
$$

So you can now rewrite your formula as a function of $G_x$ by using $(1)$ for $G(s)$ and $X(s) = G_x(s) U(s)$.